# Empty pages in Kongens Fald

Tags: scandinavian-languages, textual-history, johannes-v-jensen, the-fall-of-the-king

I'm starting to read [*Kongens Fald*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Fall_of_the_King) by Johannes V. Jensen. I find out that at the first chapter, **Mikkel** chapter, there are some empty pages.

I just want to know if the Spanish version that I bought is complete trash or if this is on purpose.